# Is there an easy way to retrieve the ISO_3166-1_numeric country codes

Tags: android, iso, country-codes

I was wondering if I can get the sim country code in [ISO_3166-1 numeric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_numeric) style in android.

I can get the 2 letter country ISO as follows:

```
TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(this.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

String ISO2=manager.getSimCountryIso();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this code,

```
TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager)getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String ISO2 = manager.getSimCountryIso();
String ISO3 = new Locale("", ISO2).getISO3Country();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get this using the `Locale` class as follows:

```
TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(this.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

String ISO2 = manager.getSimCountryIso();

String ISO3 = new Locale("", ISO2).getISO3Country()
```

Answer (score 0):

The proposed solutions using `Locale` return ISO 3166-1 alpha 3 codes, not ISO 3166-1 numeric ones. The solution I found was using the following library (in our specific case, given it is Apache 2.0 license we just copied the `CountryCode` class with some slight modifications to make it self-contained):

https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-i18n

(found in the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44821045/get-country-name-string-from-country-code-int/44821726#44821726)).

Then, your code becomes:

```
TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(this.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String ISO2 = manager.getSimCountryIso();
String ISO3_numeric = CountryCode.getByAlpha2Code(ISO2).getNumeric();
```