# Get country name String from country code int

Tags: android, locale, country-codes

I am new in Java Android.

I would like to get the name of country (String) using country code in [Locale](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html) (Ref. [ISO 3166-1 numeric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_numeric))

Tried to do something like that (where [...].getCountry() return int 826):

```
Locale countryName = new Locale("", String.valueOf(profile.getPersonnalInformation().getAddress().getCountry()));
```

and get the name of country using this: `countryName.getDisplayCountry()`

It should normally return me "**United Kingdom**" but unfortunately I have 826.

How can I do that ?

In advance thank you for your help,

Comment: @MehdiKhademloo thank you but I try to do it with int number and not string like in your example. I already tried to cast my int in String and use it but it doesn't work so your link doesn't help me. I already read it before you post it.

Comment: This is important because when you read contacts in a phone you get a number(2 digit) but when you libphonenumber you feed it an alpha-2..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now an implementation of country code ([ISO 3166-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1) [alpha-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2)/[alpha-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-3)/[numeric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_numeric)) list as Java enum is available at GitHub under Apache License version 2.0.

**Example:**

```
int c_code=profile.getPersonnalInformation().getAddress().getCountry());// 392

CountryCode cc = CountryCode.getByCode(c_code);

String country_name=cc.getName();              // "Japan"
```

**Gradle**

```
dependencies {

  compile 'com.neovisionaries:nv-i18n:1.20'

}
```

**Github**

https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-i18n

Answer (score 1):

you have to get the countricode string (2 or 3 letters) to use it. There is a opensource lib on github that will do it for you. see [Is there an open source java enum of ISO 3166-1 country codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139867/is-there-an-open-source-java-enum-of-iso-3166-1-country-codes)
or take just the enum from https://subversivebytes.wordpress.com/2013/10/07/java-iso-3166-java-enum/